# drawing shadow in core graphics is slow

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code to draw inner shadows on my UIView drawRect:

```
//add some inner shadow to the card box
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGMutablePathRef cardPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(cardPath, NULL, CGRectInset(mainRect, -42, -42));
    CGPathAddPath(cardPath, NULL, mainPathRef);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(cardPath);

    // Add the visible paths as the clipping path to the context
    CGContextAddPath(context, mainPathRef);
    CGContextClip(context);

    // Now setup the shadow properties on the context
    UIColor *innerShadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:133/255.f alpha:1.0];
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f), 30.0f, [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor]);

    // Now fill the rectangle, so the shadow gets drawn
    [innerShadowColor setFill];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, cardPath);
    CGContextEOFillPath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // Release the paths
    CGPathRelease(cardPath);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGPathRelease(mainPathRef);
```

The issue is that this is really slow. Is there any way to speed this code up a bit?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?  A 30 point shadow drawn in CG is going to be pretty slow, but there may be ways to get a similar effect using trickery with images.

Comment: How often do you actually redraw this shadow?

Comment: It's just drawn once and the results is cached.. but even drawing this once takes quite some time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, I would create shadow in image editor, save it as png and then resize and tile as needed.

Another idea is to use `shouldRasterize` property of [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shouldRasterize). It will cache the result of drawing and use it while your view remains unchanged. In this case performance depends on how often you modify your view contents.

Comment: how do you do shouldRasterize in core graphics?

Comment: There is no need to change drawRect code, you set `shouldRasterize` on `view.layer`. But if you say that you need to speed up your first drawing, then you should consider using images rather than drawing it with core graphics.

Comment: *shouldRasterize* is exactly what I was looking for in my case. Thanks, man!  Ili Spasibo :)